# How to open external website in my React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, ecmascript-6, x-frame-options

I am building a PWA with React and I want to open an external website in my app (like e. g. in the Facebook app when you click on a link the external site just slides in from the bottom in an extra window).

As my app is a PWA I could potentially use an iframe for the same effect but of course this approach is limited due to x-frame-options.

Are there any other options to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: You essentially want to run the link inside your app? Then an iframe that you mentioned is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah but due to x-frame-options this approach is really limited - try embedding Google in your html and you know what I mean

Comment: You can get the page using `fetch` or `ajax` and then render it in an element (a `div` maybe)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are other ways, `iframe` is the exact tool to accomplish what you want. `x-frame-options` exists for security reasons, if some websites don't allow other websites to load it via an iframe then they have reasons for it. The correct way of enabling such iframe is to get this particular website's permission, i.e. they should include your domain into `X-Frame-Options` as a trusted party.